# How to get stuff from database using PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

I'm new at PHP and just learning.

```
 <?php
 // database connection
 $dbhost     = "localhost";
 $dbname     = "pdo";
 $dbuser     = "root";
 $dbpass     = "7777777";

 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass)


 // echo from database
$select = $conn->query('SELECT username FROM users');
while($row = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $username = $_GET['username'];
    echo $username;
}

 ?>
```

This gives error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC in line :  $select = $conn->query('SELECT username FROM users');

Comment: Missing semicolon `;` on the line `PDO` is instantiated.

Comment: Also, looks like you should use $username = $row['username'] instead of $_GET.

Comment: Yes,i already noticed,thank you very much everyone :)

Answer (score 2):

The connection needs to be changed

```
From:
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass)

To:
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
```

The connection is missing a `;`